# SQL returning more values than it should

Tags: sql

I want to query all the Christmas that are Handmade but instead I'm getting all Christmas values.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PROD_CAT = 'Christmas' OR SEC_CAT = 'Christmas' 
AND SUB_CAT = 'Handmade' OR SEC_SUB_CAT = 'Handmade'
```

How can I get all Handmade from Christmas?

Comment: Not having a clue about your table I assume you have to group your conditions using parenthesis: `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE (PROD_CAT = 'Christmas' OR SEC_CAT = 'Christmas' )
AND (SUB_CAT = 'Handmade' OR SEC_SUB_CAT = 'Handmade')`

Comment: @Fran lol thanks now i feel stupid :(

Comment: parentheses needed for precedents. you are mixing all the condition in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On certain versions of SQL we could simplify your query even further to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE 'Christmas' IN (PROD_CAT, SEC_CAT) OR 'Handmade' IN (SUB_CAT, SEC_SUB_CAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put brackets and then you are good to go:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE (PROD_CAT = 'Christmas' OR SEC_CAT = 'Christmas') 
AND (SUB_CAT = 'Handmade' OR SEC_SUB_CAT = 'Handmade');
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses.  I presume you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE (PROD_CAT = 'Christmas' OR SEC_CAT = 'Christmas') AND
      (SUB_CAT = 'Handmade' OR SEC_SUB_CAT = 'Handmade');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parentheses to make it clear for sql what you want

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE (PROD_CAT = 'Christmas' OR SEC_CAT = 'Christmas')
AND (SUB_CAT = 'Handmade' OR SEC_SUB_CAT = 'Handmade')
```